# Should nested resources and strong params use 'model' or 'model_attributes' and why? (unpermitted parameter: model)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-forms

I have a nested form that creates an `@address` with each successful `@purchase`.

My schema and model associations are set up so that `Purchase` holds the foreign keys for everything else:

**address.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :purchases, foreign_key: :address_id
has_many :items, foreign_key: :address_id
```

**purchase.rb**

```
belongs_to :sender, class_name: "User"
belongs_to :recipient, class_name: "User"
belongs_to :address
belongs_to :item
accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
```

**item.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :purchases, foreign_key: :item_id
belongs_to :address
```

I've found [some answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14656812/associationtypemismatch-object-expected-got-hashwithindifferentaccess-in-rail) that suggest whitelisting the nested attribute params in my controller with a `.permit(address_attributes: [:name])` in the controller instead of `.permit(address: [:name])`, but neither of the two create the record.

**purchases_controller.rb**

```
def confirmation
 @item = Item.friendly.find(params[:item_id])
 @address = @transaction_wizard.transaction.build_address
end

def confirm
 current_step = params[:current_step]
 @item = Item.friendly.find(params[:item_id])
 @transaction_wizard = wizard_transaction_for_step(current_step)
 @transaction_wizard.transaction.attributes = address_params
 session[:transaction_attributes] = @transaction_wizard.transaction.attributes

 if @transaction_wizard.valid?
  next_step = wizard_transaction_next_step(current_step)
  create and return unless next_step

  redirect_to action: next_step
 else
  redirect_to action: current_step
 end
end

def create
 if @transaction_wizard.transaction.save
  redirect_to root_path, notice: "Bid sent. If you would like to cancel before it's approved, you can do so #{view_context.link_to('here', transactions_sent_unapproved_path)}.".html_safe
 else
  redirect_to item_path(@transaction_wizard.transaction.item), notice: 'There was a problem making this bid.'
 end
end

private
def address_params
 params.require(:transaction_wizard).permit(address_attributes: [:name, :street, :street_2, :city, :state, :zip_code])
end
```

Whether I use `address_attributes` or `address`, the result is the same:

```
Parameters: {"transaction_wizard"=>
             {"address"=>
              {"name"=>"name", 
               "street"=>"123 st", 
               "street_2"=>"apt 5", 
               "state"=>"AL", 
               "zip_code"=>"48489"}
             }, 
             "current_step"=>"confirmation", 
             "commit"=>"Complete offer", 
             "item_id"=>"friendly-item-id"
            }
Unpermitted parameter: address
```

This is my form:

```
<%= form_for @transaction_wizard, as: :transaction_wizard, url: confirm_item_transaction_wizard_path(@item) do |f| %>
 <%= f.fields_for :address do |address| %>
  <%= address.text_field :name %>
  <%= address.text_field :street %>
  <%= address.text_field :street_2 %>
  <%= address.text_field :city %>
  <%= address.text_field :state %>
  <%= address.text_field :zip_code %>
 <% end %>

 <%= f.submit "Submit" } %>
<% end %>
```

What gives? How can I make my controller accept these params?

---

Update: Changing `address` to `addresses` requires that I change that `@address` variable in the controller to `@address = @transaction_wizard.transaction.build_addresses`. This causes an `uninitialized constant Transaction::Addresses` error.

Comment: Did you have the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` on your Purchase model?

Comment: i do! forgot to include that in my code sample

Comment: You should use `_attributes`, may you can try to use the address plural, like `addresses`, `addresses_attributes`

Comment: no matter what i do, console output always says `unpermitted parameter: address`. also, `purchase` belongs to everything else, so `address` should remain singular, not plural. i think? also, i tried the `_attributes`. it says it in the controller code

Comment: Wait, you have a error in your relations: Address has_many purchases? you cant create a address form a purchase with this relations. You shoud use Purchase has_many address instead, i will detail it in a answer

Comment: Is that an error though? I want addresses to store only the `user_id`, so that they can be referenced in other `purchases`. It seems to me that doing this would require that `purchase` hold the foreign keys.

Comment: Why you don't relate it with a user model instead?

Comment: Thank you for the help! My `address` is associated with the `user` model. It `belongs_to :user`. I could have something confused, but what I want is for the `purchase` model to hold the foreign keys for everything else - `sender`, `recipient`, `item`, and `address` - so that their records can be referenced in other `purchases`. A `sender` makes a `purchase` for an `item` and provides an `address`. The `item` has its own `address`, and was provided by a `recipient`. When the `purchase` is successfully transferred to the `sender`, the `item` `address` is changed to the new one

Comment: Not only you have to use `address_attributes` in the strong params method, that's what your form should send too.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `address_attributes`. The problems is your relations:

To use the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` you must use `has_many` or `has_one`, and you using `belongs_to`.

In your case, relations are inverted, see:

> Purchase belongs_to Address
>
> Address has_many purchases

You can't create a address because according your relations, address is a parent model (of purchase) see [this link](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/ruby-on-rails-nested-attributes).

> Nested Attributes is a feature that allows you to save attributes of a record through its associated parent.

Comment: You can use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` on a `belongs_to` association - you just need to set `optional: true` as the presence validation will get in the way.

Comment: The OP actually has the correct setup if you want to be able to link a single address to multiple purchases yet keep track of where a specific purchase was delivered. Inversing the foreign keys or placing it on the users table does not do the job.

Answer (score 1):

You can setup nested attributes through a belongs_to association but the association must be set as optional (unless you are using Rails 4 or earlier):

```
class Address < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :purcases
end

class Purchase < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :address, optional: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
end
```

---

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Purchase, type: :model do
  it "accepts nested attributes" do
    purchase = Purchase.create!(address_attributes: { name:  'foo', street: 'bar' })
    address = purchase.address
    expect(address.persisted?).to be_truthy
    expect(address.name).to eq 'foo'
    expect(address.street).to eq 'bar'
  end
end
```

This is because nested attributes is built to work with `has_one` associations so the "parent" record is validated before the nested record so that the foreign key (the parent id) can be set on the nested record.

You should be whitelisting `address_attributes`. Nested attributes creates a setter based on the first argument:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :foo
accepts_nested_attributes_for :bars
```

This will accept `foo_attributes=` and `bars_attributes=`. This of course should follow the plurization of your assocation (singular for has_one/belongs_to, plural for has_many).

The `address=` setter on your model has nothing to with nested attributes - its created by the `belongs_to :address` association and takes an Address instance. In fact if you whitelisted that param you will get an `ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch` exception.

```
irb(main):004:0> Purchase.new.address = { street: 'foo' }
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: Address(#70264542836680) expected, got {:street=>"foo"} which is an instance of Hash(#70264511691080)
    from (irb):4
```

You also need to setup the form as:

```
<%= f.fields_for :address do |address| %>
  # ...
<% end %>
```

When using `fields_for` just pass the name of the association. You should not need to pass an instance and using `as: :address` gives the wrong parameter.

Comment: Thank you for this! A couple things: `:address` *does* need to be present. And - I'm still getting the `Unpermitted parameter: address` in console, even with `optional: true` and whitelisted `address_attributes`, and your form setup.

Comment: No - it has nothing to do with your associations. Rather you just have to make sure that your form is sending the right parameters and that you are whitelisting the correct parameters. I would start by reading the [Rails API docs on nested attributes](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) and the [guides on whitelisting](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters) instead of just relying on wild guesses.

Comment: The reason you are getting `Unpermitted parameter: address` is that `f.fields_for @address, as: :address` creates the wrong parameters.

Comment: Thanks for continuing to offer help. I am using your suggestion for the form, tho: `<%= f.fields_for :address do |address| %>`. This whole issue is occurring in last step of a wizard (which uses `ActiveModel::Model`), and I'm wondering if that has something to do with it.

Comment: Yeah, if you look at that params hash you can see that the root key is `transaction_wizard`.

Comment: Also you are not even passing the params whitelist to anything in your confirmation method.

Comment: I've updated my code with the `#confirm` and `#create` actions. The address params are being passed into `@transaction_wizard.transaction.attributes` and then into a session variable until everything is valid and can be created. Sorry for leaving that out before! I thought it was maybe not relevant.

Comment: There still are way to many question marks for me to be able to troubleshoot this line by line, and its kind of out of scope of your original question. You might want to setup a simple example of  nested attributes so that you actually understand how it works before trying to apply it to a very complex case

Comment: Nested attributes is one of those things that trip up almost everybody when learning due to the complexity and that you have to get the model, view and controller right.